# How to use python to create account on a website?

Tags: python, web-access

I am developing a website that works with Asana, so when a new user registers on my website, they should also be automatically registered on Asana as well.
How can I use python to register a new account on Asana based on the email and password provided on the sign up page of my site?

https://asana.com/

Comment: This is too broad/vague and off-topic. See: [help/on-topic], [ask].

Comment: You should check if they have an API for developers to access their sites resources from and used that, if not maybe look into using a form of web automation tool(selenium etc).

Answer (score 0):

I found the script someone posted for sign up facebook, can it be used to sign up on Asana? "usr" "pwd" should be the input on my website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

usr=input('Enter Email Id:') 
pwd=input('Enter Password:') 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
print ("Opened facebook...")
sleep(1)

a = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
a.send_keys(usr)
print ("Email Id entered...")
sleep(1)

b = driver.find_element_by_id('pass')
b.send_keys(pwd)
print ("Password entered...")

c = driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton')
c.click()
print ("Done...")

sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Sure. Selenium could be used to input data to any site